# Pagination of a List of objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I have a List of objects in my Controller

```
    public String postResults(Model model, @RequestParam String shopName) throws IOException {
        DataFilter filter = new DataFilter();
        List<Row> rows = filter.filterRows(shopName);
        model.addAttribute("results", rows);
        return "results";
    }
```

and part of the template below:

```
           <tr th:each="obj : ${results}">
               <td><img th:src="${obj.image}" th:class="images"></td>
               <td th:utext="${obj.description}"></td>
               <td th:utext="${obj.price}"></td>
           </tr>
```

Currently I'm trying to figure out how can I implement pagination here.

P.S. I already have pagination in same project based on repository and now I need to implement same without it, just with List of objects

Comment: Pagination with just with the `List of objects` will not be possible as such. You need to temporarily persist the list in memory (or storage), with some unique ID, and these unique ID should be passed along with every request to fetch the data (along with page number). But this will not be scalable solution as such. Database pagination is the one which you should go with.

Comment: You mean like this?
`List<Row> rows = filter.filterRows(shopName);
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 25);
Page<Row> page = new PageImpl<>(rows, pageable, rows.size());`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. Did this with DB help. Saved list of objects in DB and then selected it back from DB with pagination:

```
@GetMapping("/results")
    public String getResults(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        int page = 0;
        int size = 10;

        if (request.getParameter("page") != null && !request.getParameter("page").isEmpty()) {
            page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) - 1;
        }

        if (request.getParameter("size") != null && !request.getParameter("size").isEmpty()) {
            size = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("size"));
        }

        model.addAttribute("results", resultRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size)));
        return "results";
    }

    @PostMapping("/results")
    public String postResults(Model model, @RequestParam String shopName) throws IOException {
        DataFilter filter = new DataFilter();
        List<Row> rows = filter.filterRows(shopName);
        resultRepository.deleteAll();
        resultRepository.saveAll(rows);
        return "redirect:/results";
    }
```